# python inner function with argument

Tags: python

Can someone help me with this python code. I am a beginner with Python, good with java though.

```
def train_nn(iterations, batch_size, use_tf_mnist=False):
    def perPartition(it):
        if not use_tf_mnist:
            train_data = RowData(it)
            test_data = train_data
        else:
            from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
            mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
            train_data = mnist.train
            test_data = mnist.train

        return create_nn(train_data, test_data, iterations, batch_size)

    return perPartition
```

the caller only calls `train_nn(ITERATIONS, BATCH_SIZE, USE_TF_MNIST)`. So where does the inner function get its it argument from?

Comment: If `perPartition` is supposed to be an inner function, it needs to be indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`train_nn` returns the `perPartition` function as a result. It gets its argument when the caller later calls the function:

```
trained = train_nn(100, 50, False)
nn = trained(some_it)
```